# HTML/PHP link structure

Tags: php, html

I know this question was probably already answered but I just don't know what to search for, it would be helpful to at least know what I am looking for.

So what I'd like to do is have link in which there is a number of article to display, like this:

```
www.mywebpage.com/store/article/[article no.]
```

Where article no. is just plain number(for example 12345). I'd like to read it in my php script and I'd like the link to be without the ?article=[article no.] which is generated in get method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [.htaccess mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

some examples of using it: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/More_.htaccess_mod_rewrite_examples

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this. I'd also like to thank others for answers.

Answer (score 0):

*mod_rewrite* is the thing you want.  In your PHP script, use var_dump($_GET) to see the HTTP request argument.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is redirect script flow to the runnable file handeling the articles. You can achieve this with .htaccess files and mod_rewrite if you are using Apache.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^store/article/([0-9]+)$ myscript.php?article=$1
```

This will redirect the script flow internally so that myscript.php sees it as if you accessed `myscript.php?article=123` for article number 123 but you will be able to access that with the link `store/article/123`.

Thus you can access the article number in `myscript.php` with `$_GET['article']`.